# build path wizard creation for eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am developing a development tool for a language. I did my own editor , error checking and all. now I need to do the build path in the eclipse for my tool. and I need to add my compiler to run my program . how can I do that. is there any good tutorials please help me to find it or help me to do that.

I have my own compiler which is a jar file. I need to specify the compiler path pro-grammatically .I need to do run as - > my application.

Comment: Can you please add more details so your question is bit more clear?

Comment: This is a large subject - start with the [Program debug and launch support](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fdebug.htm) section of the plug-in developer guide